# Error #1046 - No database selected SQL import on XAMPP

Tags: mysql, sql, drupal, phpmyadmin, xampp

I am trying to import the SQL database from my Drupal production site into a sandbox testing site on my local machine. I currently use XAMPP on my machine here at work.

I have downloaded my db `aipiadxxm_if9DHdr.sql` and then I go to the phpMyAdmin on `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/index.php` then to -> Import.

After I import the db I get this Error:

```
SQL query:
--
-- Database: `aipiadxxm_if9DHdr.sql`
--
-- --------------------------------------------------------
--
-- Table structure for table `if9d_access`
--
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `if9d_access` (
`aid` int( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`mask` varchar( 255 ) NOT NULL default '',
`type` varchar( 255 ) NOT NULL default '',
`status` tinyint( 4 ) NOT NULL default '0',
PRIMARY KEY ( `aid` )
) ENGINE = MYISAM DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT =1;


MySQL said: Documentation
#1046 - No database selected
```

What is causing this error message: `#1046 - No database selected` ?

Comment: It looks like the .sql file is just the table. Try creating the database in phpmyadmin, then importing the file as a table.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You need to create and/or select the database on your sandbox machine before importing the SQL for the table structure and data.

In phpMyAdmin, this means choosing a database from the sidebar and *then* using its import tab. If the database you want to fill doesn't exist, you have to create it first using the `Create new database` form.

After import, you should confirm that the export-import process hasn't affected the [anonymous user record](http://drupal.org/node/1029506) (uid 0).

Comment: thanks! that did the trick. good lookin out on the anonymous user record too.