# phpmyadmin import database error

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I try to import a MySQL database on the localhost through phpmyadmin and i receive this error. what it means? and how can i solve it? any ideas?

```
SQL query:

--
-- Database: `casasdl_mag`
--
--
-- Database: `casasdl`
--
-- --------------------------------------------------------
--
-- Table structure for table `admin_assert`
--
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `admin_assert` (

 `assert_id` INT( 10 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT  'Assert ID',
 `assert_type` VARCHAR( 20 ) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT  'Assert Type',
 `assert_data` TEXT COMMENT  'Assert Data',
PRIMARY KEY (  `assert_id` )
) ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8 COMMENT =  'Admin Assert Table' AUTO_INCREMENT =1;

MySQL said: Documentation

#1046 - No database selected
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error #1046 - No database selected SQL import on XAMPP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438427/error-1046-no-database-selected-sql-import-on-xampp)

Comment: Prepend your sql dump with `use casasdl;`

Comment: Well, obviously you haven't selected a database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a table you need to select a database for that table to insert into

```
USE databaseName;
```

run this before your script

```
USE casasdl;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `admin_assert` (

 `assert_id` INT( 10 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT  'Assert ID',
 `assert_type` VARCHAR( 20 ) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT  'Assert Type',
 `assert_data` TEXT COMMENT  'Assert Data',
PRIMARY KEY (  `assert_id` )
) ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8 COMMENT =  'Admin Assert Table' AUTO_INCREMENT =1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Like you can read in error, you have to select your database.

Add `USE yourDatabase;` at the beginning of the code.

Comment: i feel so dumb that i asked this now, it was really simple

Answer (score 1):

mysql or each db backend should import your tables into a Database , so it needs you introduce a db name , indeed you should tell to mysql :

```
use mydbname;
```

you can create it from :

```
mysqladmin -uroot -p create mydbname
mysql -uroot -p mydbname < mysqlfile.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using external php, then do not use `use database` syntax or `mysql-select_db("database");` syntax. Instead use `mysqli_connect` which accept database name.

Answer (score 0):

The `USE db_name` statement tells MySQL to use the db_name database as the default (current) database for subsequent statements. The database remains the default until the end of the session or another USE statement is issued.

Refer: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/use.html

Answer (score 0):

Another option is within phpmyadmin Select DB from the left sidebar and inside it import will work.

Comment: That will junk database if you combine it with another database