# Import localhost.sql backup phpMyAdmin

Tags: import, phpmyadmin, localhost

I'm using MAMP (osx) to test my website local.
Because I recently switched to a new Macbook I took a backup from my database with phpMyAdmin.

I did this by going to phpMyAdmin and click on the export tab and selected all the databases and saved the file to localhost.sql (8,9mb).

Now when I try to import that file (going to phpMyAdmin, selecting the import tab and then browsing to the localhost.sql file) it show me this error:

## 1046 - No database selected

How can I import all of my databases again into phpMyAdmin?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error #1046 - No database selected SQL import on XAMPP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438427/error-1046-no-database-selected-sql-import-on-xampp)

Comment: @Howli No, this is not a duplicate. This problem refers to the case when one is exporting and importing multiple databases (actually all existing databases, i.e. localhost.sql), whereas the other one refers to a specific database. I've had the same issue described here, and the solution below helped.

Answer (score 1):

If you select "Custom" from the Export options radio buttons, then look down to the "Object creation options" area, check the box for `Add CREATE DATABASE / USE statement`. This should add the proper statements to your export. Perhaps this should be the default when exporting multiple databases, but at least that will enable you to move your data around.[image: Add CREATE DATABASE / USE statement checkbox]