# "No database selected" when importing in phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I was making a wordpress site on my localhost using xampp and now I want to upload it to a hosting server. But when i want to import the datebase from phpMyAdmin I get this error:
[image: error while importing]

```
Error
```

SQL query:

--

### -- Database: `cdcol`

### -- --------------------------------------------------------

### -- Table structure for table `cds`

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `cds` (

`titel` VARCHAR( 200 ) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL ,
 `interpret` VARCHAR( 200 ) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL ,
 `jahr` INT( 11 ) DEFAULT NULL ,
 `id` BIGINT( 20 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE = MYISAM AUTO_INCREMENT =7 DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1 COLLATE = latin1_general_ci;

MySQL said: Documentation

## 1046 - No database selected

What is the problem and what I need to do to solv it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error #1046 - No database selected SQL import on XAMPP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438427/error-1046-no-database-selected-sql-import-on-xampp)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the problem is right there in the error message:  you haven't said which database you want to put this data in.

either create a new one, or click on the one you want to use from the left menu.

Comment: oh... I'm just so unhandy when comes to work with phpMyAdmin. it's working now. thx for heads up!